# Google sign in with Firebase on Flutter logs in without selecting google account or authorizing it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement a sign in with google on a flutter app using firebaseAuth, the user can log in just fine, but I've realized that the app doesn't ask for a google account nor does it ask for authorization if I delete the account in the firebase console.
This is my google Sign in method:

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
    await googleUser?.authentication;


final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
);

return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

}

I've tried changing the way the sign out happens but nothing changed, currently using `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()`

For signing out.

Comment: the access token is good for sn hour once that expires it should then run through a new authentication flow

Comment: @DaImTo Unfortunately it doesn't, I've tried loging in a day after the authentication and it still didn't ask for a new one